# Не работает значение времени в hide(), show()

Tags: jquery

При использовании метода hide() или show(), страница не обращает внимание на скорость выставленную в круглых скобках, и в результате сразу скрывает или сразу показывает объект. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$('#forheader').hide(8000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была подключена **slim версия** библиотеки jQuery, как оказалось она не поддерживает временные значения в методе hide(), поэтому элемент страницы сразу пропадал.

Решение: подключить **обычную (полную) версию** библиотеки jQuery.

п.с. Я методом большого количества проб, нашел ответ. Решил не удалять вопрос, так как поиск ничего на этот счет не выдает, может кому то тоже пригодится и кто-то сэкономит время.